# Select last 10 entries in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In [SO Question/ Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720745/mongoose-find-last-ten-entries-in-database) there are still some parameters for basis of query.

I am looking for simple query like

```
p.find().limit(10).exec(function(err, qry){
  return qry;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var q = models.Post.find().sort('date', -1).limit(10);
q.execFind(function(err, posts) {
  // will be of length 10
});
```

Comment: Did this actually work for anybody ever? Didn't work for me and 6 months earlier there was a correct answer using `sort({'date': -1})`
The right answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15081087/3462536

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me with Mongoose 3.8.16:

```
var query = ModelName.find({}, null, {limit: 10, sort: {'epoch': -1}});
query.exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
```

This gives the last 10 entries in the DB sorted by the field `epoch`.